# Is this space handling of pmatrix environment official?

Tags: matrices

For example, if we enter the code

```
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e \\
f
\end{pmatrix}
```

it occurs following matrix:

```
a b c
d e
f
```

not error.

My question is that this space handling official function? (To be exact, function that if number of `&` is not same per line, matrix is outputted by left-aligned)

If this function is official, please tell me reliable source written this function.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't understand your question. Why should there be an error?

Comment: I don't think "should". But I feel a sense of discomfort. For example, about array environment, code as same as above code occurs error, doesn't it?

Comment: The code above does not produce the output you claimed. The `discomfort` must have another cause here

Comment: No, replacing `pmatrix` with `array` in your snippet does not produce an error. I don't really see why you would be worried about this ...

Comment: Oh, I misunderstand. Thanks for some comments.

Comment: what does it mean to be official?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely the expected result. Missing cells are implicitly filled up.

Answer (score 1):

if by "official", you mean "is this how this environment is defined to work", yes, it is.

the definition is part of the `amsmath` package, which is documented in the `amsmath` user's guide, `texdoc amsmath`.

as egreg has pointed out in a comment, "Missing cells are implicitly filled up."

Answer (score 0):

Compiling

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e \\
f
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

as expected.

Comment: And why is this the answer? (Admitted, the question is totally unclear)

Comment: Thanks for comment and testing. But this is not answer of my question. My question is "To be exact, is this function official?".

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just wanted to explain that the question was not clear. To show that I needed an image.

Comment: @yassu If I read well page 10 of the amsmath package documentation, I see nothing surprising in the spacing obtained with my code. I do not know about official functions in `LaTeX`. I am missing something maybe.

Comment: The OP knows it works in the implementation, the question was/is: is that the documented behaviour _in the specification_ of amsmath,